# Updating a single field in react is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, crud, mern

I hope you all are good. I am trying to create an update function in Mern, when I tried it on Postman it works fine but when I 'am trying to implement same with React it does not give me any result and also not giving me any error. I 'am unable to figure out What I'am doing wrong. If anyone here can figure out by looking on my code, what is wrong with it, It will be great help. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
import { getANews, updateNews } from "../../actions/news";

const Edit = ({ router }) => {
    const [websiteCategory, setWebsiteCategory] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        initNews();
    }, [router]);

    // get a single news to make changes on it
    const initNews = () => {
        if (router.query._id) {
            getANews(router.query._id).then((data) => {
                if (data.error) {
                    console.log(data.error);
                } else {
                    setWebsiteCategory(data.websiteCategory);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    const onChangeWebsiteCategory = (event) => {
        setWebsiteCategory( event.target.value);
    };

    // update the category field in this particular news
    const editNews = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        updateNews(router.query.id, websiteCategory).then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                console.log("error");
            } else {
                console.log(websiteCategory);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Edit News</h3>
            <form onSubmit={editNews}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Website-Category </label>
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    defaultValue={websiteCategory}
                    onChange={onChangeWebsiteCategory}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit News" className="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Edit);
```

**Edit:** Thanks for the reply, below is the complete code. Hope this helps you helping me :)

This is my action/news file

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import { API } from "../config";
// API = http://localhost:3000/


export const getANews = (id) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/news/${id}`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

export const updateNews = (id) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/news/${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include `updateNews`

Comment: What are you trying to update? What is the error ? Please specify the necessary information !

Comment: can you show the code of your updateNews() action?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine. I do not have your ....action/news implementation. So can't run your code.

may I suggest your line 25-26 be switched to

> setWebsiteCategory(event.target.value);

[you code in my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBOk1.png)

I looked at your code have repeated your problem.  useEffect 2nd parameter should be an empty array.  so the initialization is called once in the begining. (read "Preventing Endless Callbacks using Dependencies" section of https://blog.bitsrc.io/fetching-data-in-react-using-hooks-c6fdd71cb24a

```
see https://codepen.io/lukelee10/pen/VweGByb
```

is what i have jested up.  the getANews and updateNews from line 46 - 53 are my stubbed out call to the API (notice they are both async function(meaning they return promise).

SO, your take away is line 54 - 97.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I tried your suggestion but the issue is still same,  also when I try to update the field  from frontend  the field itself is getting removed. But when I try same from postman the field comes again and get updated as I want. I have edited my OP to include complete code. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: I am not too familiar with useEffect function.  I think you were trying to initialize the *function component with initNews function.  Why not just call it directly? meaning taking off `useEffect(() => { ` and `}, [route])`

**by the way, try passing in {location} rather than ({route}). your withRoute will cause location to be passed in, not route.

***push come to shove, you can put in `debugger` through out the code and you can see in context what and where the error is --do "inspect" on the browser's page and you should be able to see the context of the call.

Comment: Thanks Luke for replying. I 'm getting no errors, in fact on updating I am getting success message but the field get updated with null. I tried removing useEffect() but the issue is still same.

Comment: see the new answer edited above.  or see..https://codepen.io/lukelee10/pen/VweGByb

Comment: Hi Luke, Thank you for your efforts, I appreciate time you're spending on this issue.  I missed to mention that it is a Next.js project. So, when I tried your suggestion it is giving me error -  location undefined. And when in my code I remove router from second parameter of useEffect it is giving me 'news id undefined' because it does not load the news without mentioning router as second parameter.

Comment: The I am at a lost here.  The `useEffect(() => {initNews()}, [router]);` means that do not call initNews unless your router is changed.  judging from you `<input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            defaultValue={websiteCategory}
            onChange={onChangeWebsiteCategory}
          />` defaultValue can only be set once within the component, but your field gets set to null means your component gets completely reloaded ---probably because of Next.js.  
Would you have this project on github or show me your package.json please.

Comment: Hi Luke, I have edited my question with package.json file along with some other information. If you can suggest anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, earlier I was not sending category in my update function. So I removed my update function from action file and fetch the data in my function and send the updated data back in the body.

```
const editNews = () => {
    return fetch(`${API}/news/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(websiteCategory),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```